# NoSuchMethodError while running Spark Streaming job on HDP 2.2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, spark-streaming

I am trying to run a simple streaming job on HDP 2.2 Sandbox but facing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error. I am able to run SparkPi example on this machine without an issue.

Following are the versions I am using-

```
    <kafka.version>0.8.2.0</kafka.version>
    <twitter4j.version>4.0.2</twitter4j.version>
    <spark-version>1.2.1</spark-version>
    <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
```

Code Snippet -

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TweetSenseKafkaConsumer").setMaster("yarn-cluster");
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(5));
```

Error text from Node Manager UI-

> Exception in thread "Driver" scala.MatchError:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less; (of class
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError)  at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:432)
>   15/02/12 15:07:23 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark
>   context initialization ... 1 15/02/12 15:07:33 INFO
>   yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization ... 2

Job is accepted in YARN but it never goes into RUNNING status.

I was thinking it is due to Scala version differences. I tried changing POM configuration but still not able to fix the error.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: " I tried changing POM configuration but still not able to fix the error." What changes did you make? According to the Spark doc "For the Scala API, Spark 1.2.0 uses Scala 2.10. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.10.x)." - you're using 2.11, which may well be your problem

Comment: Actually, earlier I specified dependency for spark-streaming_2.10 ( Spark compiled with Scala 2.10).  I did not specify dependency for Scala compiler itself. It seems Maven automatically pulled 2.11 (Maybe due to some other dependency). When trying to debug this issue, I added a dependency on Scala compiler 2.11. Now after your comment I changed that dependency to 2.10 and it is working. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Earlier I specified dependency for spark-streaming_2.10 ( Spark compiled with Scala 2.10). I did not specify dependency for Scala compiler itself. It seems Maven automatically pulled 2.11 (Maybe due to some other dependency). When trying to debug this issue, I added a dependency on Scala compiler 2.11. Now after Paul's comment I changed that Scala dependency version to 2.10 and it is working.